# How to open an already opened window on the focused monitor

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, taskbar

I want to know if I can open an already opened window(monitor 1 for example) on the focused monitor(monitor 2) so it moves the window to the **focused** one.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGKJS.jpg)

Any help or tips are appreciated!

Comment: You can use the `Win+Shift+Right` keyboard shortcut to move the window to the active monitor after it's focused.

Comment: I am already aware of this. I was just wondering if there is an auomatic solution.